# GNUPlot with Excel data

Tags: excel, gnuplot, graphing

Not sure if this belongs here or in the math forum, but I figured it was kind of like software so I'll post here.

So I have data in an excel spreadsheet that I need to graph with GnuPlot because I've exceeded 65550 data entries (yes, I need them all) and excel breaks it down into two graphs. So I saved the file as a CSV file, and got gnu to plot the data. The problem is, I have 2 columns (4 technically, 2 are continuations of the first two columns) and I want to plot one against the other, X being a time increment, Y being the data read from a probe at that time. I can plot Y if I delete the X columns, and the graph looks correct, except the X-axis label gives the sample number (or row number) instead of the time variable. How do I plot sample at the time interval in the other columns of the data file? This is my setup:

```
set title "Output vs Time"
set xlabel "Time (us)"
set ylabel "Output"
set grid
set datafile sep','
plot 'path\path\datafile.csv'
```

(I'm obscuring the information a little to not give away my project - I need to keep my job...lol)

Maybe this will post correctly, pardon if not, but here's sample data I need to post:

```
0           0               0.010083147 535.7200172
5E-14       6.17302E-21     0.010083369 535.7309953
7.56681E-14 9.9272E-21      0.010083592 535.7419968
1.27004E-13 1.71606E-20     0.010083814 535.7530215
2.29677E-13 3.33029E-20     0.010084036 535.764069
4.23216E-13 9.45538E-20     0.010084258 535.7751391
```

the data in the third column is a continuation from the first, and in the fourth column, a continuation of the second.

Plot looks right except the X axis. Also, how do I get rid of the path name at the top of the graph? The file path name shows up there and I need to get rid of it. Thanks for the help in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

In order to give you a really good answer, we'd need to know what the datafile looks like (the first 5 or 6 rows should be good enough).  However, without seeing it, you need to at least include a `using` specifier in your plot command

```
#x values taken from first column, y values taken from second column
plot 'path/to/datafile.csv' using 1:2, '-' using 3:4
```

Comment: So the data in the CSV file is set up like so:

0         0          0.010083147 535.7200172
5E-14         6.17302E-21  0.010083369 535.7309953
7.56681E-14 9.9272E-21  0.010083592 535.7419968
1.27004E-13 1.71606E-20  0.010083814 535.7530215
2.29677E-13 3.33029E-20  0.010084036 535.764069
4.23216E-13 9.45538E-20  0.010084258 535.7751391

Let me know if you can't read the data correctly. There are 4 columns, X, Y, X, Y.

I haven't used gnuplot since the earlier editions so I'm probably missing a new tip or trick...

Comment: Ok, that did it. So any idea how to get rid of the path label on top of the graph?

Comment: actually - I just noticed that was a legend. I think I might be able to figure out how to edit that, thanks!!

Comment: Sorry, just noticed now that it plots the first two columns, but does not plot the second two columns. and if I say "using 1:2:3:4" I get an error saying too many specs for this type...

Comment: @JediEngineer -- To get rid of the legend you can do `unset key`, or to remove a particular legend entry you can append `notitle` onto the plot command.  As for plotting all 4 columns, did you look at my edit?  I actually plot the file twice.  Once `using 1:2` and once `using 3:4`

Comment: I did thanks!! But there's a problem still -the excel graph is correct, the gnuplot graph is wrong and I'm not sure why. Basically, I'm using data from Multisim Electronics workbench simulations. I run the simulation for approximately 20ms, then take the data and plot it. I'm plotting each voltage reading against each time index, and there's over 130,000 of them per graph. But what is gnu doing that it looks incorrect? It almost seems as if it's not plotting all the data points because where I should have a funky looking sinewave, I have a perfect sine wave...

Comment: What I'm saying is that the sinewave should show a "zero on time" between peaks, and it doesn't. GnuPlot shows just a sinewave. Any Ideas?

Comment: Disregard that - found the problem